# Ranking: Only allowing features to have positive weights

Tags: feature-selection, skewness, ranking

I read the following in the [Google "rules for machine learning"](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/rules-of-ml#rule_14_starting_with_an_interpretable_model_makes_debugging_easier):

> *Rule #35: Beware of the inherent skew in ranking problems.*
>
> - *Only allow features to have **positive weights.** Thus, any good feature will be better than a feature that is "unknown"*.

1. What do they mean by that? How would you accomplish that at training time?
2. Why would "any good feature" be better than a feature that is unknown?